# DateTime Conversion error while using CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am using `EF 6 Code Firs`t and creating a `User` and A `Role` and associating the `user` to the `Role` in `Seed` Method.

```
AppUserManager userManager = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<AppUser>(context));
AppRoleManager roleManager = new AppRoleManager(new RoleStore<AppRole>(context));

string roleName = "Administrators";
string userName = "Admin";
string password = "Admin@2016";
string email = "admin@admin.com";

if (roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
{
    roleManager.Create(new AppRole(roleName));
}
AppUser user = userManager.FindByName(userName);
if (user == null)
{
    userManager.Create(new AppUser {UserName = userName, Email = email}, password);
    user = userManager.FindByName(userName);
}
if (!userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, roleName))
    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName);
```

But I am getting The `conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated error while executing the following statement.
userManager.Create(new AppUser {UserName = userName, Email = email}, password);`

There is a field in `IdentityUser` base class called `LockoutEndDateUtc` it's type is `DateTime`? and in Database it is being correctly modeled as `nullable`.

I have seen other posts which instructs me to populate the date fields. But as it is `nullable` why should I populate it?

Yet I tried to initialize it like this:
`LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(3)`
But still no luck.

I am not understanding why this error is popping up. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what DBMS are you using? I think Sql Server has problems with Datetime columns. try adding modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("datetime2")); in this case.

Comment: Hi I am using SQL Server. I used Code First Migrations. It worked. Thanks for the info. Will try.